# SonarJ like tool for .NET

Tags: .net

I'm looking for a tool like [SonarJ](http://www.hello2morrow.com/products/sonarj) but for .NET instead of Java.

> SonarJ helps you to find deviations
>   between he architecture and the code
>   within minutes. It can be integrated
>   into your IDE to help you avoid the
>   introduction of new architetural
>   violations to your code base. You can
>   also use it to maintain metric based
>   software quality rules which will keep
>   complexity under control.

I googled and searched SO without satisfying results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two others:

Lattix  (http://www.lattix.com)
NDepend (http://www.ndepend.com)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the *Neeraj Sangal* answer, the tool NDepend:

- can detect architectural violations through Code Rules over LINQ Queries (CQLinq) like for example: [UI layer shouldn't use directly DB types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_UI_layer_shouldn%27t_use_directly_DB_types.html)
- comes with [82 code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx), that can be used to define new custom code metrics like the popular [C.R.A.P metric](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_C.R.A.P_method_code_metric.html)
- comes with many default (and *customizable*) code quality rules like [Quick summary of methods to refactor](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Quick_summary_of_methods_to_refactor.html)
- is integrated in VisualStudio 2012, 2010 and 2008
- can be [integrated into your build process](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx) and build report
- can also help for [code diff and code review](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Diff.aspx) scenarios

NDepend also comes with an interactive UI with [interactive dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx),  [interactive dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) and [interactive treemap view to visualize code metric](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Treemap.aspx). Here are screenshot:

[image: Dependency Matrix and Dependency Graph]
[image: Dependency Matrix and treemap]
[image: CQLinq code rule edition]

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool NDepend*